# FIP Error during file installation

Tags: tooltwist

We get the below error during FIP installation, any idea why?

> InstallerUtil v1.2, incorporating fip v1.3  launchpad=ITStagingLaunchpad, type=test
>   Indexing destination...
>   ERROR: tooltwist.fip.FipException Unknown response from FIP server: 500
>   Exception: tooltwist.fip.FipException: tooltwist.fip.FipException: Unknown response from FIP server: 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '500' is an HTTP status code. Looking at wikipedia...

> 500 Internal Server Error A generic error message, given when no more
>   specific message is suitable.[2]

FIP doesn't return any error information that might help someone hack or crack it's operation, so you'll need to look at the output of fipserver on the destination machine.

If you started fipserver using nohup so it wouldn't hang up when you log off, using

```
nohup ./fipserver 39393 &
```

then the output will be in a file named nohup.out, in the same directory.